# Figure out whether storeage is an adopted or external

Tags: android

Starting from marshmallow, android allows users to use sdcard as an adopted storage.

I need to figure out whether a sdcard is beeing used as an adopted media or not and I need to get such information with standard Android SDK (in other words, it must run at standard android devices, so I can't assume root access).

When the sdcard is beeing used as external media:

```
File[] externalDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null); >>> length = 2
Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(externalDirs[1]); >>> returns true
Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated(externalDirs[1]); >>> returns false
((StorageManager)context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE)).getStorageVolumes().get(1).isPrimary() >>> returns false
```

When the sdcard is beeing used as adopted media:

```
File[] externalDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null); >>> length = 1
Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(externalDirs[0]); >>> returns false
Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated(externalDirs[0]); >>> returns true
((StorageManager)context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE)).getStorageVolumes().get(0).isPrimary() >>> returns true
```

How can I know when my sdcard is acting as adopted storage?

Comment: For the record, you can use the SDK to execute root commands. You need access to finish then, but using the regular SDK doesn't mean no root tools

Comment: @Zoe Thank you for clarifying it. Does not help anyway once I intended to say that I need execute the code in standard android devices with has no root access at runtime. I wrote it clearer now.